# Prove that $P_1(A>B, A>C) > P_2(A>B, A>C)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Not a homework question, but a problem I need to solve in real life. Seems easy at first, but somehow I cannot prove tha:

A,B,C are independent random variables under each of the two probability measures $P_1$ and $P_2$, In addition, we know that $P_1(A>B) > P_2(A>B)$ and $P_1(A>C) > P_2(A>C)$. Prove that $P_1(A>B, A>C) > P_2(A>B, A>C)$.

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean by bonus? You are ordering others to solve or request? Because it doesn't seem to be request.

Comment: @JeanMarie, this will not work since A>B does not have to be independent of A>C.

Comment: @cruvadom You are right. I delete this silly explanation.

Comment: @MeesdeVries, I try to decompose it somehow using the independecy, but nothing leads to the desired outcome.

Comment: What do you call "real life", where one would need to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result doesn't hold. Under different probabilities, random variables $A,B$ and $C$ have different distributions. Here's a counterexample for the question.

Let $A,B$ and $C$ be independent random variables with distributions:

- Under measure $P_1$:
  $$ A:\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{0}{0.8}\,\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{2}{0.2}\right),\quad B,C : \left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{-1}{0.75}\,\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{1}{0.25}\right) $$
- Under measure $P_2$:
  $$ A:\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{0}{0.3}\,\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{2}{0.7}\right),\quad B,C : \left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{-1}{0.2}\,\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{1}{0.8}\right)$$

Then, easy calculation gives:
$$P_1(A>B)=0.8>0.76=P_2(A>B)\ \\P_1(A>C)=0.8>0.76=P_2(A>C),$$
but, on the other hand:
$$ P_1(A>B,A>C) = 0.65 < 0.712 = P_2(A>B,A>C). $$